# How to run a cronjob every 50 minutes?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cron-task

I want to run cron job in following manner

00:00
00:50
01:40
02:30
and so on

how can i setup cron tab so it works like this

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score -3):

You should try this:

```
$schedule->command('import:production')->cron('*/50 * * * * *')->withoutOverlapping();
```

Comment: Already tried it, it will run in this way 00:50,01:00,01:50,02:00,02:50 ....

problem is that its also running every hour, which is not desired

Also you have used 6 values, originally it should be 5 only

Comment: Just set it to 50 instead of */50